# Dividing point clouds into quadrants in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have an array of 30 points in 3 dimensions cast as a numpy array in python:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.round(np.random.random((30,3))*20)
b = b - b.mean(axis=0)
```

I want to separate these points into eight quadrants with reference to the "center of mass" of the point cloud. I could do something like this:

```
for a in (b, -b):
    q_list = a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]>0][a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]>0][:,2]>0]
    quad_list.append(q_list * sign)
    q_list = a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]>0][a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]>0][:,2]<=0]
    quad_list.append(q_list * sign)             
    q_list = a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]<=0][a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]<=0][:,2]>0]
    quad_list.append(q_list * sign)              
    q_list = a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]<=0][a[a[:,0]>0.][a[a[:,0]>0.][:,1]<=0][:,2]<=0]
    quad_list.append(q_list * sign)
    sign *= -1
```

This works fine, of course. It returns a list with eight arrays of position coordinates, each of which contains only the points that lie in a particular quadrant. However I get the feeling that there should be clearer, more concise way to handle this. Suggestions?

Comment: Something like this could be nice: `np.packbits(b > 0.0, axis=1) >> 5`. It labels the quadrants 0-7 but maybe not in the desired order.

Comment: If it doesn't label them in the desired order it would be relatively easy to add a lookup table to map the desired order onto the actual numbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution. It should work for an arbitrary number of dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

def split_into_quadrants(points, idx=0):
    if idx < points.shape[-1]:
        positive = points[points[:, idx] >= 0]
        negative = points[points[:, idx] < 0]
        return (split_into_quadrants(positive, idx+1) +
                split_into_quadrants(negative, idx+1))
    else:
        return [points]

b = np.round(np.random.random((30,3))*20)
b = b - b.mean(axis=0)
print(split_into_quadrants(b))
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tested it against my own corrected code and the results agree. This was this kind of thing I was hoping to learn. I have never even imagined a recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion may be too computationally heavy for large arrays.

A better option may a function that can return the point themselves divided into quarters or just return the index of the quarter without recursion (still should work for an arbitrary number of dimensions).

```
import numpy as np

def split_into_quadrants(points, get_quadrants_index=False):
   ndims = points.shape[1]
   existing_quadrants = list(itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=ndims))
   quadrants_dict = dict(zip(existing_quadrants,range(len(existing_quadrants))))
   sign_points = np.sign(points)
   quadrants_idx = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: quadrants_dict[(tuple(x.astype(int)))], 1, sign_points)
   if get_quadrants_index:
       return quadrants_idx
   points_split_into_quadrants = []
   for i in set(quadrants_idx):
       points_split_into_quadrants.append(points[quadrants_idx==i])
   return points_split_into_quadrants

b = np.round(np.random.random((30,3))*20)
b = b - b.mean(axis=0)
print(split_into_quadrants(b,get_quadrants_index=False))
```